# namerror when trying to plot return value

Tags: python

I am training a GAN and using a function to train the model. For the output, I would like to create lists, losses_G and losses_D, to track performance of the GAN which I can plot (using matplotlib).

```
def train(self, dataLoader, lr, num_epochs, criterion):

    losses_G = []
    losses_D = []

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):

        running_D_loss = 0
        running_G_loss = 0

        for index, real_X in enumerate(dataLoader):

            # TODO device
            labels = torch.ones(real_X.shape[0], 1)
            self.discriminator.zero_grad()
            real_X = real_X.type(torch.float32)

            # real forward
            output = self.discriminator(real_X)
            error_D_real = criterion(output, labels)
            error_D_real.backward()
            D_x = output.mean().item()

            # fake forward
            labels_fake = torch.zeros(real_X.shape[0], 1)
            noise = torch.randn(real_X.shape[0], 100)
            fake_data = self.generator(noise)
            output = self.discriminator(fake_data.detach().squeeze())

            error_D_fake = criterion(output, labels_fake)
            error_D_fake.backward()
            D_G_z1 = output.mean().item()
            
            optimizer_D.step()

            # generator
            labels.fill_(1)
            self.generator.zero_grad()

            output = self.discriminator(fake_data)
            error_G = criterion(output, labels)
            D_G_z2 = output.mean().item()
            error_G.backward()

            optimizer_G.step()

            error_D = error_D_real + error_D_fake
            running_D_loss += error_D.item()
            running_G_loss += error_G.item()

            if index % 1 == 0:
                print(f'epoch {epoch + 1}, index {index + 1}: g_loss={running_G_loss:.4f}, d_loss={running_D_loss:.4f}')        
                print(f'D(x): {D_x:.3f}, D(G(z)): {D_G_z1:.3f} {D_G_z2:.3f}')
                print()

                #possible point of differences to get code to print losses
                
        losses_G.append(running_G_loss)
        losses_D.append(running_D_loss)
    return losses_G, losses_D
    
 x= train (self, dataLoader, lr, num_epochs, criterion)
 print (x)
```

As a sanity check, I tried to print out the return value of the function but instead of getting the full list for each index that is run, I am only getting the final value.

Any help on this?

Comment: `if index % 1 == 0` will always succeed.

Comment: sorry, I just realized the last two lines didn't copy over correctly. They are supposed to be outdented

Comment: You're only appending `running_G_loss` at the end of the inner loop. So you don't get the running losses, just the final value for each `real_X`.

Comment: Will it work then if I indent it to the inner loop?

Comment: If that's what you want, yes.